# RestTemplate giving 500 Internal server error sometimes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, resttemplate

I'm having piece of code which is calling a REST api using RestTemplate. Everything is working perfectly fine in my local system. But after deploying in other environment, the code in not working in first attempt. It gives `org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError`. However, if I call this method again it works. I don't know why this is behaving strangely. Every even attempt is working in my case. Here is my code block:

```
final String url = this.environment.getProperty("app.base-uri") + "/testEmail/";

final HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
httpHeaders.set(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, this.getRequestAuthorizationHeader());

final HttpEntity<EmailRequestModel> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(emailRequestModel, httpHeaders);

final ResponseEntity<String> emailResponseEntity = new RestTemplate().postForEntity(url, httpEntity, String.class);
```

Here are the logs:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError:
   at org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException.create (HttpServerErrorException.java100)
   at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError (DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java172)
   at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError (DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java112)
   at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError (ResponseErrorHandler.java63)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse (RestTemplate.java785)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute (RestTemplate.java743)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute (RestTemplate.java677)
   at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity (RestTemplate.java452)
   at com.toyota.tmi.service.impl.ExtraRequestServiceImpl.sendWorkflowEmail (ExtraRequestServiceImpl.java1153)
```

Can you please give me any clue why is this behaving strangely. I'm not able to figure it out from logs. Thanks.

Comment: Try to call your api using postman and check what is error accutually ? If you can see console of api then see what happens their

Comment: @Eklavya no issues with POSTMAN. I suspect that RestTemplate has something to do with environment.

Comment: Maybe you could try wrapping the call in a try catch block and logging out the exception that is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see any error in service side as well or it's only client side.
The code snap you have provided seems fine.